# Call inner function of jQuery-Plugin-function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I've written an jQuery-Plugin, which I want to use as Object. So I declared some functions within the plugin, which I want to call from any other location, just like an object with methods. Is that even possible?

To keep it simple:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
        // Here I want methods...
        function foo()
        {
             // do something...
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then I want to call the inner function from outside the plugin like:

```
$.myPlugin.foo();
```

But that doesn't seem to work. So is it even possible? Or are there any other solutions? I don't want to use an normal unrelated jQuery-Class for this purpose. Because this plugin should work together with some other jQuery-Plugins.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = (function(){
        // Here I want methods...
        this.foo = function()
        {
             // do something...
        }
    })();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution seems to fit my requirements. Unfortunately you've got an error in your code. You will have to leave out the `();` after the method-declaration, since it doesn't work with them :)

Comment: I'm probably a bit rusty in javascript. Feel free to edit my post if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.fn` and re-write your code like this:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
        // Here I want methods...
        $.fn.myPlugin.foo = function()
        {
             // do something...
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And you can call it like:

```
myPlugin().foo;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works great. I'd rather prefer the solution of Alexandre C. It seems more elegant.

Comment: @faileN: Sure you can go with that but note that it is essentially the same thing :)

Comment: Yupp I know. Didn't say yours is wrong :) I just thought that Alexandre C. solution is more elegant :P

Comment: @faileN: Yes it looks more elegant :)

Comment: Why isn't this working for me? I copied it exactly but an error:  `myPlugin is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery docs site [recommends a good way of doing it](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing): make `$.fn.myPlugin` take the name of your function as its first parameter and pass all remaining arguments to the correct function. The example code is somewhat lengthy, so go to that site to look at it.

Comment: That's also a pretty cool solution. But this is to much overflow for only one method I want to have in my plugin :) Thanks though. I will keep that in mind for bigger tasks :)